# Get ImportError when trying to runserver

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a django application which works when I runserver in local. My problem is that I copied my project packages in server and now when I try to runserver I get ImportError

I searched a lot and I tried everything but they did not work.
things including :

1- activating virtual env

2- installing django(`pip install django` cmd and `sudo pip install django` as well)

3- using python and python3 in cmd

I get the error when I try to run this command:

`python3 manage.py runserver`

````
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?```
````

Comment: if you have multiple version of python kernels, then pip should be somehow `pip3` when you use `python3` I think.

Comment: if you have activated virtual environment, then first check from terminal python shell ```import django``` works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the directory of your virtual environment, then it won't work again.

Run
`pip freeze`
to see the installed packages in the environment,

It's better to create a new virtualenv and install django then activate or run `pip install` inside the environment but its better to create a new env.

**Windows**

```
 pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
 mkvirtualenv myEnv
 workon myEnv
```

**linux**

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
virtualenv myEnv
. myEnv/bin/activate
```

then install django

```
pip install django
```

try to run django

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

if you move your virtualenv activate script in env doesnt work. you can update it to work again. update env path in activate file.
if your environment doesnt activated then `pip install` run for python2 you must run `pip3 install`